# PHP include text file and format

Tags: php, html, text-files, font-size

I have a simple text file. The file name is kpop.txt - What I want to do is include the contents of the file in a webpage. I am using php for includes (header / footer stuff).

I would like the contents of the kpop.txt file to remain formatted similar to it's current form. The only real difference that I would like to make is to increase the font size.

I am currently using

```
<?php
include("kpop.txt");
?>
```

I have also tried

```
<pre>
<font size ="12">
<?php
include("kpop.txt");
?>
</font>
</pre>
```

What I want to see is my text like this but simply with a larger font.

```
FTUS43 KGGW 271140
TAF
KP01 271140Z 2706/2806 08010KT P6SM SCT140
     FM271500 12011KT P6SM SCT110
     FM271900 14011KT P6SM BKN120
     FM280000 14008KT P6SM VCSH BKN100
     FM280300 13006KT P6SM VCSH SCT100
      AMD NOT SKED. UNFL=

TAF
KM75 271140Z 2706/2806 07008KT P6SM SCT110
     FM271500 11008KT P6SM FEW150
      AMD NOT SKED. UNFL=
```

Another solution that did not work is

```
    <?php

    myfilename = "kpop.txt";
    $TAF = file_get_contents(myfilename);
    $TAFlines = explode("\n", $TAF);

    //echo $TAF;
    echo $TAFlines;


}
?>
```

I have also tried using the file_get_contents function along with an explode function but cannot seem to get that to work properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"Another solution that did not work is"* - You seem to have left out the `$` signs for the `myfilename` variables here. If they are in fact part of your real try, you need to edit your question. Theoretically, that will throw an undefined constant error.

Comment: So the font tag did not make the text larger? That is odd. Or is the problem the formatting? In that case you should use `<pre>` tag to maintain the extra spacings. I'm a bit curious about the TAF. What does the `P6SM` mean? I have never seen that message in my country.

Comment: @Andreas I would expect the `<font>` tag, inside the `<pre>` tag, to be ouput as literal text.

Comment: @FKEinternet you are right. I can't understand how I missed that. Twice too.

Comment: Sorry I was typing this code and not copy pasting. Yes there is supposed to be a $ in front of myfilename.

Comment: @Andreas - TAF stands for Terminal Aerodrome Forecast. the P6SM stands for six statute miles visibility or greater.

Answer (score 5):

So this is what I came up with.

```
<pre>
<?php

//Read in the file and increase the font 200%
$TAF = file_get_contents("kpop.txt");
echo "<div style='font-size:200%'><p>$TAF</p></div>";

?>
</pre>
```

It may not be pretty but it works. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use CSS, rather than the deprecated `<font>` tag:

```
<pre style="font-size:120%">
<?php echo file_get_contents('kpop.txt') ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Font tags work fine on all browsers still. That shouldn't be the problem. But I do wonder if they will ever remove the font functionality from browsers.

Comment: They still work *now*, but for browsers that *do* following the standards your code won't work, and if the rest of the browsers follow suit, that means you have to go back and update all of your code.  My philosophy is fix the problem now so you don't have to do it later, especially if you're writing new code..

Comment: In that case no browsers follow the standards. And font tag has been deprecated for many years now. I'm not saying you are wrong in your way of thinking, just that I don't think that is the problem here.

Comment: It's probably just as well no browsers follow the standards - or at least still support the old ones.  There *is* something to be said for backward compatibility!

Comment: @Andreas -- Two words: (in)valid code.

Comment: @FrankConijn what is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, use `fopen()` and then read it `fread()`,just use `echo` to display it:

```
   <?php
    $myfile = fopen("kpop.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo '<span style="font-size:30px;">' . fread($myfile,filesize("kpop.txt"))
. ' </span>';
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
```

More details: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp

Comment: Why not using `file_get_contents` directly?

Comment: Thanks Djordje. That however does not solve my problem. What I needed was for the layout of the text to remain the same, but with a larger font.

Comment: Thanks 63d26a1c- I actually did try that. I even stated that in my original post.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for @Rex

Comment: @Rex oh I have just seen that you answered your question. Never mind then, I'm glad you have found solution that works for you :)