# PHP - I can't save content from input

Tags: php, html, web, networking

I am struggling with the problem on my website. I should create an form to fill which will display new information/news. I have code like this:

```
    <?php
include "0begin.php";

$title=$_POST["title"];
isset($title) or $title=$_GET["title"];
$msg=$_POST["msg"];
isset($msg) or $msg=$_GET["msg"];

?>
<h1>News</h1>

<form method="POST">
Title<br><input type=text input name="title" value=<?=$title?> ><br>
News<br>
<textarea input name="msg" cols=40 rows=5> </textarea><br>
<input type="submit">
<br><br>
</form>
<?php
$dateposted=date("YmdHis");
if (!empty($title) and !empty($msg)) {
    $fp=fopen("/home/aqueen/public_html/news/".$dateposted."txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp,$title,$msg);
    fwirte($fp,$msg);
    fclose($fp);    
    include "/home/aqueen/public_html/news/".$dateposted."txt"; }

?>
```

My questions:
1) How can I fix that code? It generates new file but without content inside. 
2) It doesn't show the new file on the website /probably doesn't include it properly/
3) When it starts working- how I can let someone delete news from website without opening the code? /online/

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You have some errors in your code. for example: <input type=text input name="title" value=<?=$title?> must be <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=$title?>" >

Comment: And typo "fwirte". Use fread and not include to get the content of your file. I would consider writing data to a DB instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360673/php-include-text-file-and-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
//include "0begin.php";
$title = $_POST["title"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
?>
<h1>News</h1>
<form method="POST">
    Title<br>
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    News<br>
    <textarea name="msg" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
    <br><br>
</form>

<?php
$dateposted=date("YmdHis");

if (!empty($title) and !empty($msg)) {
    if (!file_exists('news/')) {
        mkdir("news/", 0755);
    }

    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/news/")){
        $pathGenerated = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/news/";
    }
    if(file_exists( "news/")){
        $pathGenerated = "news/";
    }
    $pathGenerated = str_replace('//', '', $pathGenerated);

    $fp=fopen($pathGenerated."".$dateposted.".txt", "w");
    $textInsert = "Titolo: ".$title." \nMessaggio: ".$msg;
    fwrite($fp,$textInsert);
    fclose($fp);
    include $pathGenerated."".$dateposted.".txt";
}
?>
```

Auto create folder `/news/` if not exist.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sadly it doesn't seem to work. The files aren't created in the folder news.

Comment: Remove your folder /news/, automatically php recreate folder with correct permission. If not work again print this `print_r($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` and show me result.

Comment: And active show error in php. (first line of file add this)
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Well, I deleted the folder and it appeared again- but still it isn't saving files there. I am not sure where I should print_r... In my file?

Comment: Insert ini_set display error in your file (first line after <?php). And print_r in your file var `print_r($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`

Comment: I tried to do so but I am helpless at PHP. It doesn't show anything and I am working on school server- so I am not sure if it will display anything.

Comment: @KimikoSourire i edit my original answer. Re-try new code... now work?

Comment: Thank you so much! You really did it *.* Now it is working and I am so sorry- I am new to PHP and the tasks we get in the university are way too difficult to me. Thank you again for your help

Comment: I have one more question- how can I change it that it doesn't replace one file with another while displaying? I would like to keep all things which are sent on my website and while sending form these are replaced

Comment: @KimikoSourire how replaced? The file is created based on time and millisecond data!